# SwiftのSpritekitで円グラフを書く方法

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

現在、SwiftのSpriteKitを使いiOSアプリケーションを作っているのですが、円グラフを書く方法がわかりません。
調べてみてもUIKitを使う方法ばかり出てきてしまい、使うことができません。
誰かSwiftのSpriteKitで下のような円グラフを描く方法をご教授ください。

[このリンク先のような円グラフを描きたいです](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-K2Us5zyEGJs/U4rt4SgHxVI/AAAAAAAACGo/IBfgQ2C1jxE/s800/ProgressCircle.png)

Comment: 円グラフ(pie chart)ではありませんが、[A circular progress timer for SpriteKit games written in swift](https://github.com/tib/ProgressNode) が参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

SpriteKitの話でなくて、WatchKitの話の引用ですが……

[WatchKit のカスタムUI実現方法のまとめ](http://qiita.com/shu223/items/e704f70abc50da32ba38)

Appleのプログラマが、予想外のローテクを使っているというお話です。

連番の円グラフの画像を使うというのは、SpriteKitでも、有効なテクニックではないでしょうか？
1%きざみで100枚画像を用意するのはたいへんですが、5%きざみ程度ですむなら、20枚くらい用意すればいいので、それほど苦労はいらないはず。

「いやいや、ドロー（SKShapeNode）で円グラフを書きたいんだよ」ということでしたら、その旨コメントしていただくか、質問文に加筆していただくか、お願いします。